# Disallow rule in the robots file

Tags: robots.txt

Disallow: /*?

For a website which has this in the robots.txt file. I am presuming all will be blocked before the ?.

Is this true? All levels/folder before the /? ?

Answer (score 1):

That rule would block every URL that contains a query string. So it would block `http://www.example.com/foo.html?name=bar`, but it would not block `http://www.example.com/foo.html`.